# Plaid Link Issue when connecting to Chase "You may need to update your app in order to connect to Chase"

Tags: plaid

I am making my own personal financial application with React and Django. I am trying to connect to my chase account with the "development" plaid environment. When I try to add my Chase account it shows
"You may need to update your app in order to connect to Chase".

Any idea on how I can connect my app to my Chase account with "development" access?

I launch Link to create an access token to my chase account, but Plaid is showing that I may need to update the app in order to connect to Chase.

Answer (score 2):

Chase requires an OAuth connection to work with Plaid. If you’re getting this error you haven’t completed all the requirements for using OAuth with Chase, such as getting Production access approval and filling out the questionnaire. (Or, if you have completed all the requirements, you haven’t been enabled for Chase OAuth yet — it takes a week or two.) You can find more details in the OAuth docs at https://plaid.com/docs/link/oauth/